# Best way to display a PNG with a drop shadow effect on it?

Tags: html, css, photoshop

I have a PNG that has a drop shadow affect on it...Since I have to place the image in my CSS as a block, rather than the rounded rectangle that it is - how can I maintain that effect with the shadow working with the non-white background?

Right now I have a simple stroke and drop shadow effect to it per here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AT52R.png

I have read about shell commands, but is there a CSS property that will allow me to allow my block to look like this?  Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you use CSS3 `border-radius` and `box-shadow` to create the box, instead of an image?

Comment: Must be a very heavy rock the OP is living under ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

But wait! You can do this entirely without images. Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8KgV9/1). It's not completely cross browser (IE < 9 won't handle rounded corners or box shadow), but it's very close to what you want. Just play around with some values to fine tune it.

```
div
{
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 3px solid #0088ff;
    border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 5px #888;
    -ms-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 5px #888;
    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 5px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 5px #888;
}
```

In terms of IE compatibility, there's a good solution [here](http://css3pie.com/). There are more comprehensive docs on the site, but essentially you download `pie.htc`, put it in your root folder and add `behavior: url(pie.htc)` in your CSS file.